# Adding topography to base maps using Surfer?

Tags: topography, surfer

I want to add the topography map with extension (BLN) to my the map which I create it using the Surfer prog, I put only the country board.

How can I add the topography maps as a background using the surfer program?

Answer (score 3):

To add the BLN file to your map in Surfer version 14 or 15, select the map you want to add it to, and then click **Home | Add to Map | Layer | Base**, select the BLN file and click **Open**. A new base layer is added to your map from the BLN file.

If you are using a different version of Surfer, the command could be in a slightly different place. For example, in older versions (e.g. Surfer versions 9-13) , you would select the map you want to add it to and click **Map | Add | Base Layer**, select the BLN file and click **Open**. Then the BLN is added to the map as a base layer.